# Why is permission denied for opening my file?

Tags: r, permissions, shiny

Here is my code for an R Shiny App:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(nycflights13)
library(DT)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

parguera <- read.csv("C:/Users/Anatoly/Documents/Collatz/RenameLater/RenameLater/MapsAndSuch")
#monaisland <-
#islacatalina <-

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("NOAA Caribbean Coral Data"),
  leafletOutput("mymap"),
  p(),
  actionButton("laparguera", "La Parguera Data"),
  actionButton("mona", "Mona Island Data"),
  actionButton("isla", "Isla Catalina Data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 17.95, lng = - 67.05, popup = "La Parguera ") %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 18.00, lng = -67.50, popup = "Mona Island") %>%
      addMarkers(lat = 18.2, lng = -69.00, popup = "Isla Catalina")
    })
  observeEvent(input$laparguera, {
    output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(parguera, options = list(pagelength = 25)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run this, it says Permission denied.

When I comment out the line reading in the CSV file it works, so I think the problem lies there.

Why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: is it running on your desktop or on shinyapps.io?

Comment: Well, as it is it is not running at all, but I am only running it on my desktop now, through the Viewer panel.

Comment: Is it normal that your CSV file doesn't have no extension?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is an extension?

Comment: If it helps, this is the path I get when I click on "open file location". My CSV file is in the same file as the Shiny App.

Comment: If `MapsAndSuch` is the file name try to add  `.csv` at the end

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension

Comment: Does your code need to open an "output" file or temp file of any kind?  Perhaps that set of files aren't being allowed to open?

Comment: There's an example online: https://gist.github.com/psychemedia/9690079 which sounds rather similar.  You may want to try loading their example and see what happens.

Comment: Here:  This is a better example, and it shows the tests done to accept a CSV file: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html

Comment: Thank you for all your help, Bee Kay. I tried adding .csv, but that didn't work, and the error message is the same as before. I will read the links and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I am not sure whether my code needs to open an output file. How can I find this out?

Comment: Also, when I ask whether the file I am trying to read exists, it says TRUE.

Comment: are you sure it's not a folder?

Comment: Ah, thank you HubertL!!! I was missing /RShinyCoral.csv

Comment: And thank you Bee Kay, you were essentially right, I just didn't put 2 and 2 together

Answer (score 0):

While I am not familiar with this tool, perhaps your "path" to the file should read "C:\Users\Anatoly... instead of "C:/Users/Anatoly/...."

Comment: you need to double backslashes, but slashs are usually just fine

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I tried this, and got the following error: Error : '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"

Comment: OK - so it uses / got it.  How about file extension matching problems?  And have you tried a very simple .csv format file with just the columns and one or two data points?